# Permutation of MATHSBOMBE :

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Of all the possible word formed by the permutation ( including non-sensical word ).
 If you were to arrange all the words in alphabetical order, what would be the position of the word 'MATHSBOMBE ' be?

For example: If you have these letters 'A E G L N `. Total word = 120(5!). The position of the word 'ANGLE ' is 22nd.

I have calculated the position of the word 'MATHSBOMBE '. 
I am not sure about my answer: 
My answer : 2115445 th position.

Not sure of a mathematical way of writing the answer using notations .

Comment: Do you mean permutations of all of the letters of MATHSBOMBE?

Comment: Yes. Including all the non sensual words... And putting them in alphabetical order.

Comment: I arrive at the same result as I. Cavey.

Comment: That means it's right. I have checked it and it works.

Comment: I double counted that's y mine is wrong

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to [an on-going maths contest](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/mathsbombe/problem.php?index=1).

Comment: According to information given to me, this contest has now expired. Unlocking and undeleting the answers.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a slick way to do it, so slow and methodical it is.

You letters are: A B B E H M M O S T.

With A,E, or H first there are $\frac{9!}{2!2!}$ words. With B first there are $\frac{9!}{2!}$ words.

Then we are to words beginning 'MA'. The remaining letters are: B B E H M O S T. With B first, there are $7!$ words. With E,H,M,O,S first there are $\frac{7!}{2!}$ words.

Then we are to words beginning 'MAT'. The remaining letters are: B B E H M O S. With B first, there are $6!$ words. With E first there are $\frac{6!}{2!}$ words.

Then we are to words beginning 'MATH'. The remaining letters are: B B E M O S. With B first, there are $5!$ words. With E,M, or O first there are $\frac{5!}{2!}$ words.

Then we are to words beginning 'MATHSB'. The remaining letters are: B E M O. With B,E or M first, there are $3!$ words.

Then we are to words beginning 'MATHSBO'. The remaining letters are: B E M. With B or E first, there are $2!$ words.

The next word alphabetically is 'MATHSBOMBE'.

Putting it all together, I count $3\cdot\frac{9!}{2!2!}+\frac{9!}{2!}+7!+5\cdot\frac{7!}{2!}+6!+\frac{6!}{2!}+5!+3\cdot\frac{5!}{2!}+3\cdot3!+2\cdot2!=472642.$

Thus your word is the 472,643rd word. Note that this does not agree with your answer (although it's possible I made an arithmetic error as well). There are only $\frac{10!}{2!2!}$ distinct permutations of the letters (this is less than $2115445$). I suspect you double counted by neglecting to account for letters that are repeated. This is the dividing by $2!$ trick used often above. To see why this is the case, play around permuting the letters of an easier word like BILL. To see why I wrote $2!$ instead of just $2$, play around permuting the letters of a word like MOMMY.

Comment: I have definitely double counted. I will ch check again.